# How to ignore case in javascript while comparing two APIs response in postman?

Tags: javascript, postman, lodash

I am using below function to compare two API responses but some keys have same value but as case is different than it reports that as a difference. How to avoid this case sensitivity?

```
var difference = (object, base) => {
    function changes(object, base) {
        return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
            if(!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
                result[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value;
            }
        });
    }
    return changes(object, base);
}
```

I want it to not show difference when there is any case issue. for example for below it should not return any difference and consider it same

```
"content": “Data | 8GB
or
"content": “data | 8GB
```

Response of First API

```
[
 {
    "price": 20,
    "planCategory": "Mobile Broadband",
    "externalSkuId": “MBB”,
    "planHeader": {},
    "expiry": "14 days",
    "includedData": 8,
    "includedDataType": "GB",
    "inclusionOption1": "Get 1GB bonus data on every automatic recharge when you opt-in. T&C apply.",
    "inclusionHighlight": "8GB",
    "inclusionOptions": [
      {
        "channels": [
          "SELF_SERVICE",
          "ESTORE"
        ],
        "type": {
          "name": "DATA"
        },
        "content": "data | 8GB"
      },
      {
        "channels": [
          "SELF_SERVICE"
        ],
        "type": {
          "name": "OTHER"
        },
        "content": "expiry|14 days"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Second API response

```
[
 {
    "price": 20,
    "planCategory": "Mobile Broadband",
    "externalSkuId": “MBB”,
    "planHeader": {},
    "expiry": "13 days",
    "includedData": 8,
    "includedDataType": "GB",
    "inclusionOption1": "Get 2GB bonus data on every automatic recharge.",
    "inclusionHighlight": "8GB",
    "inclusionOptions": [
      {
        "channels": [
          "SELF_SERVICE",
          "ESTORE"
        ],
        "type": {
          "name": "DATA"
        },
        "content": “Data | 8GB"
      },
      {
        "channels": [
          "SELF_SERVICE"
        ],
        "type": {
          "name": "OTHER"
        },
        "content": “Expiry|14 days"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How I am calling difference function

```
//First API response body
var jsonObject1 = pm.globals.get("responseBodyAPI1”);
//Second API response body
var jsonObject2 = JSON.parse(responseBody);
//Call the difference function stored in global variable and pass response body of both APIs in that
var diff = eval(pm.globals.get("difference"))(jsonObject1, jsonObject2); 
//Log the difference of both APIs on Postman console
console.log(diff);
```

Difference Function Result in Postman Console shows case sensitive issues as well I just want it to return empty object in this case as Expiry or expiry and Data or data are same thing
[image]

```
var jsonObject1 = pm.globals.get("response");

const lowserCase = (obj) => { 
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (key == "content"){
        key = key.toLowerCase(); 
        }
    });
};
jsonObject1.forEach(lowserCase);

console.log(jsonObject1)
```

The above code is not working

Comment: Shouldn't you tag `lodash` or `underscore`? I was going to just answer with the obvious "convert both strings to same case before comparing" but when you read your code that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converted only "content" on left side of pipe sign to lower case using below.

```
//Change to lower case from left side of | sign for content
jsonObject1.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (value.inclusionOptions) {
        value.inclusionOptions.forEach(function(value2, index2) {
            var tokens = value2.content.split('|');
            value2.content = tokens[0].toLowerCase() + "|" + tokens[1];
        });
    }
});
console.log(jsonObject1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could with taking the response as string and comparing the lowercase version of each:

```js
function isSame(res1, res2) {
  return JSON.stringify(res1).toLowerCase() == JSON.stringify(res2).toLowerCase()
}

console.log( isSame({"DATA": "X"}, {"data": "x"}) )
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdi. I am actually passing response of both APIs in above difference function and data is not only one case insensitive issue there is another one "Expiry". Response of both APIs is huge it is array and I have posted partial response in my question just to show what I am expecting

Comment: You want to ignore some properties of the response object while checking ?

Comment: No. I want if there is any case difference than ignore the case - compare.

Comment: the function i wort above will ignore any case difference between the two response ? what's missing ? you can make the two response same as well by appliying the lowerCase to both then reverting them to object by using JSON.parse(str)

Comment: basicly do a response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response).toLowerCase()) before passing them to your change function

Comment: Yes I considered that to be last option. As I have to report all the actual differences that what is missing in API 2 so if I change the case of all response I then have to manually convert back values to its actual case before reporting. I added another code which is not working Can you look into that?

Answer (score 0):

Use an Intl.Collator with `sensitivity: 'base'`, this means equivalent letters are the same weight. Much more efficient than `toLower`. Here is a very efficient object comparer that doesn't need toLower or JSON.stringify and ignores case when the properties are strings.

```js
const  compareStr = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }).compare;

const compare = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Array.isArray(obj1)
    ? Array.isArray(obj2) && obj1.length === obj2.length && obj1.every((item, index) => compare(item, obj2[index]))
    : obj1 instanceof Date
    ? obj2 instanceof Date && obj1.getDate() === obj2.getDate()
    : obj1 && typeof obj1 === 'object'
    ? obj2 && typeof obj2 === 'object' &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).length === Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).length &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).every(prop => compare(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]))
    : typeof obj1 === 'string' && typeof obj2 === 'string'
    ? compareStr(obj1, obj2) === 0
    : obj1 === obj2;

console.log(compare({ prop: 'a' }, { prop: 'A' }));

console.log(compare(['b'], ['B']));

console.log(compare('a', 'A'));

console.log(compare('B', 'b'));

console.log(compare('B', 'a'));

console.log(compare('Mismatched case', 'MisMatched Case'));
```